# PDFAnnotExtractor 0.1l causes an error with class file versions 55.0

Tags: hyperref, pdf, texlive, bugs, oberdiek

Faced a problem with PDFAnnotExtractor 0.1l. Problem with update of `PDFAnnotExtractor`?

Just try in `TeXLive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\pax\`

```
java -jar pax.jar
```

And get an error (with last updated Java 1.8.0_321)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: pax/PDFAnnotExtractor has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Comment: well pax has an issue tracker now. So why don't you report it there? (Along with a minimal example and other details.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I dotnt know about issue tracker of pax. Is it on github?

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/pax